# Why is the auth_key parameter empty?

Tags: flash, flex3, vk

I've created a flex-based application and uploaded it to [vkontakte](http://vkontakte.ru). For some reason the auth-key parameter (at the flash vars) is empty, how come?

Here is a [link](http://vkontakte.ru/app1549899_47745507) to the application.

**EDIT:**

Here is my application tag inside the site:

```
<embed width="607" height="590" flashvars="api_id=1549899&amp;viewer_id=47745507&
amp;viewer_type=2&amp;user_id=47745507&amp;group_id=0&amp;is_app_user=1&amp;
auth_key=&amp;language=3" allowscriptaccess="never" allownetworking="internal"
allowfullscreen="true"
quality="high" name="player" id="player" style="" src="http://cs1830.vkontakte.ru  
/u47745507/13de6ae4d52c69.zip" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

Here is other application tag inside the site:

```
<embed width="607" height="570" flashvars="api_id=1457219&amp;viewer_id=47745507&
amp;viewer_type=0&amp;user_id=0&amp;group_id=0&amp;is_app_user=1&
amp;auth_key=2a3d8454de9f7a7ada0750050e686b01&amp;language=3" allowscriptaccess="never" 
allownetworking="all" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" name="player" id="player" 
style="" src="http://cs4232.vkontakte.ru/u1304144/c1fd79dcbe47ec.zip" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it's a social network site and like facebook, you'll have to create a user.

Comment: Don't think many here will register for the site just for the question. Post the html & AS here and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to register to this site just to answer this question (thou it would be nice). I'd like to get help from an already registered user that is familiar with this site (I got that most of the site's users are Russian). HTML/AS won't help in this case, since the auth_key parameter is given by the site and is empty at my application, but has value at different applications.

Comment: I would still suggest posting the AS code, even though it's site specific, it does sound like a code error ;-)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the AS. By using Fire Bug, I can see that the auth_key param at the flashvars is empty where in different applications it has a value.

Comment: The problem might be in the html or the js. Can't say anything without seeing the code.

Comment: I've added the HTML where you can clearly see that the auth_key parameter is not passed on. I suspect a site policy, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing application settings, you must "payment on" in the "Payments" tab. Then parameter auth_key will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

If the auth_key parameter is set by some javascript in the web page, there is noway we can guess why it's not being set without seeing that javascript. This issue apparently is not your problem - at least not your SWF's problem - the problem exists somewhere else. Contact the site's administrator for assistance. user_id parameter for the second (the working one) code is 0, which could be some default/moderator value. May be your user_id doesn't have those privileges - this is a 'wildest' guess.

Comment: (-1) I'm sorry, but "ask someone to help you" is definitely not an answer.

Comment: This is the only answer you will get. This is a configuration problem with vkontakte. This is definitely not a flash/flex problem. This probably doesn't even belong on stack overflow because there's no evidence it's a programming problem.